# Jenkins CI pipeline radiator

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, pipeline

We have many build pipelines running in Jenkins, each for separate projects and with multiple jobs (test, integration, deploy, quality, performance, release etc).

I am looking for some sort of radiator that will provide an aggregate single-page view of all pipelines, indicating if any have single jobs broken.

However, having looked around I can't find anything suitable. Has anyone seen anything similar at all? Would appreciate some pointers before attempting to build one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Gerolds suggestion above, the [Categorized Jobs View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Categorized+Jobs+View) plugin is able to aggregate a number of select jobs and therefore provide a single-page view on multiple pipelines (see attached).

[image: aggregate pipeline view]

Answer (score 0):

Radiator? Click on the + right of your view's tab on your Dashboard. There's a view of type [Radiator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin):

> *Shows status with high visibility, suitable for display in an extreme feedback system. You can choose which jobs are to be displayed in which view, in the same way as the list view.*

And there's also the [Categorized Jobs View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Categorized+Jobs+View):

> *Besides showing items in the list format, allows creation of categories of jobs*

Comment: You must have plugins for both of those views @Gerold? 
They're not provided by default (Jenkins 1.616)

Comment: @AndrewEells Yes, you do: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Categorized+Jobs+View

Comment: Thanks @Gerold, the Categorized Jobs View is able to aggregate select groups of jobs once the plugin is installed, which is exactly what I was after.